# Liked list memory freeing issue/memory leak

Tags: c, linked-list, valgrind

i have a memory leak in one function that i dont understand why its happening and have no idea how to fix it.
The function purpose is to rearrange the linked list in terms of the values of key1, it works completely fine but for some reason its having a memeory leak/im not freeing it properly

```
void ascending1 (Node * node, int A){
    int i = 0;
    double Temp_Key1[A];
    int Temp_Val[A];
    double Temp_Key2[A];
   double temp2 = 0;
    double temp3 = 0;
    int temp1 = 0;
    int amount = 0;
    int x = 0;

    for ( i = 0; i < A; i++ ){
        Temp_Key1[i] = 0;
        Temp_Key2[i] = 0;
        Temp_Val[i] = 0;
    }

    Node *sort1_head;
    sort1_head = NULL;
    for (i = 0; i<A ; i++ ){
        Temp_Key1[i] = node->key1;
        Temp_Key2[i] = node->key2;
        Temp_Val[i] = node->value;
        node = node->next;
    }

    amount = A-1;
    while (x<=amount){
     for (i = 0; i<A ; i++ ){

         if (Temp_Key1[i] < Temp_Key1[i+1]){
             temp2 = Temp_Key1[i];
             Temp_Key1[i] = Temp_Key1[i+1];
             Temp_Key1[i+1] = temp2;

             temp3 = Temp_Key2[i];
             Temp_Key2[i] = Temp_Key2[i+1];
             Temp_Key2[i+1] = temp3;

             temp1 = Temp_Val[i];
            Temp_Val[i] = Temp_Val[i+1];
            Temp_Val[i+1] = temp1;
         }
    }
        x++;
    }

    for ( i = A ; i >= 0 ; i--){
      node = malloc(sizeof(Node));
      node->value = Temp_Val[i];
      node->key1 =  Temp_Key1[i];
      node->key2 =  Temp_Key2[i];
      node->sort1 = sort1_head;  
      sort1_head = node;
      }

    printf("\n");
    printf("Following the sort1 links:\n");
    print_list1(node);
    sort1_head = NULL;
    free_list(node);
}
```

The function that frees it is

```
 void free_list(Node * head){
    Node * new_head = head;
    Node * old_node = NULL;

    while (new_head != NULL){
        old_node = new_head;
        new_head = new_head->next;
        free(old_node);
    }

}
```

Valgrind gives me the following error:

```
==20167== Conditional jump or move depends on uninitialised value(s)
==20167==    at 0x10928C: free_list (FuncDef.c:19)
==20167==    by 0x109B24: ascending1 (FuncDef.c:199)
==20167==    by 0x10922D: main (main.c:26)
==20167==  Uninitialised value was created by a heap allocation
==20167==    at 0x483577F: malloc (in /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/valgrind/vgpreload_memcheck-amd64-linux.so)
==20167==    by 0x109A75: ascending1 (FuncDef.c:181)
==20167==    by 0x10922D: main (main.c:26)
==20167== 
==20167== 
==20167== HEAP SUMMARY:
==20167==     in use at exit: 48 bytes in 1 blocks
==20167==   total heap usage: 6 allocs, 5 frees, 2,240 bytes allocated
```

Comment: Nowhere in the code you've shown is any sort of assignment made to any `Node::next` value, which `free_list` is accessing.

Comment: rearranging a linked list is modifying the contents of the `next` (and if doubly linked, `prev`) pointer(s) There is no need to be calling `malloc()` nor `free()`.

Comment: Please post the struct definition of each node in the linked list

Comment: regarding: the function signature: `void free_list(Node * head){`  at some point, the `head` pointer needs to be set to NULL.  To do that the code needs to pass a pointer to a pointer to `head`.  however, the code fails to do that

Comment: the posted code does not compile!  Please post a [mcve] so we can reproduce the problem and help you debug it.

Comment: @bruno wow really okay thank you, I undeleted it

Answer (score 0):

Your loops are wrong:

```
for (i = 0; i<A ; i++ ){
   if (Temp_Key1[i] < Temp_Key1[i+1]){
```

but for `i` is `A-1`, there is no `Temp_Key1[i+1]`, i.e, there is no `Temp_Key1[A`].

The same for your loop

```
for ( i = A ; i >= 0 ; i--){
    node->value = Temp_Val[i];
```

there is no `Temp_Val[A]`.

Just change to

```
for (i = 0; i<A-1 ; i++ ){
```

and

```
for ( i = A-1; i >= 0 ; i--){
```

Comment: Hello thanks for your comment. Unfourntantly it didnt work, it still had the same issue